# laravel query relationship to check if data exists

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a set up like this,

**QUIZ MODEL**

```
public function scores()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Score');
}
```

**SCORE MODEL**

```
public function quiz()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Quiz');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**USER MODEL**

```
public function scores()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Score');
}
```

Some background, a quiz should only be playable by a user if that user does not already have a score for said quiz, what I am wanting to do is that if a user has a relationship with a quiz via having a score I want to stop that quiz being return in the query, here is my attempt,

```
$quiz = Quiz::with('questions.answers')
        ->has('scores.user', 2)
        ->whereDate('date_playable', '=', $date)
        ->first();
```

However this returns no quizes regardless of whether the user has a score for it or not. Can anyone enlighten me on how to only return quizes that a user does not currently have a score for?

Comment: You are not filtering anywhere for a specific user though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently searching for a quiz that does not have more than 2 scores for **any** user.

What you need is [whereDoesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) instead:

```
$quiz = Quiz::with('questions.answers')
    ->whereDoesntHave('scores', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
    })
    ->whereDate('date_playable', '=', $date)
    ->first();
```

Where `$user` is the `App\User` instance that you are querying for.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple approaches to achieve that outcome. I am thinking about creating a many to many relationship between Quizzes and Users, taking scores as the middle table.

```
User
{
    public function quizzes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Quiz::class, 'scores');
    }
}
```

Then to get the desired quiz:

```
$quiz = Quiz::with('questions.answers')
    ->whereKeyNot($user->quizzes()->pluck('id')->all())
    ->whereDate('date_playable', '=', $date)
    ->first();
```